# How to convert string data with variable format to datetime?

Tags: python, datetime, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe that has a column of time in string format as below:

```
 id       playTime

 12       1d 13h 23m
 13      42d 22h 47m
 14       7d 16h 31m
 15        1h 26m 6s 
 16           9d 58m
```

I `tried pd.to_datetime(df['playTime'], format='%j%H%M%S')` but it shows `time data does not match format '%j%H%M%S' (match). In the end, I'd like to convert the`df['playTime']`values to seconds.`

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense, what you have is a collection of time durations, there is nothing here to indicate a date. For instance what should the first row represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) for [Timedelta](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html)s with [`total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html):

```
df['playTime'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['playTime']).dt.total_seconds().astype(int)
print (df)
   id  playTime
0  12    134580
1  13   3710820
2  14    664260
3  15      5166
4  16    781080
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['playTime'], format='%j %H %M %S')
```